# What's the best way to store object in array in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

trying to figure out what column type to user in parse.com to store list of object and found out the common answer is to use arrays.

wanted to know, what's the best approach? to store list of ids? list of names? (if i got this column in the other object)

any known way to use it?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried that yet and found it to not work well? Or are you still in the planning/design stage?

Comment: Have you look at the parse documentation it has a section for working with arrays: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects

Comment: Thanks guys, i just assume both approaches will work (IDs or Names) but i'm trying to figure out if there's any recommended approach and why. my needs are to store a few references to object in one array 
(

Comment: Thanks Guys, i actually believe the 2 approaches will work (ids and names) but i'm trying to understand if there's a recommended one and why? my needs are to store in an array list of few objects (not more than 10)